# Can ARM64 run ARM assembly in compatibility mode?

Tags: android, native, android-8.0-oreo, arm64

It's a 3rd party library and I do not have access to it's source code -  asking them to build for ARM64 had no effect so far, despite they claim Android 8.0 (which is ARM64 only) would be "supported".

The following Java code runs on `armv7l`, but fails on `aarch64`:

```
static {
    switch(System.getProperty("os.arch")){
        case "aarch64":
        case "armv7l":
            try {
               System.loadLibrary("somelibrary");
            } catch(UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

> dlopen failed: "/data/app/ ... /base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a/somelibrary.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit.

It seems, as if the `AArch32` execution would be "optional" (and possibly not even available) - because one would (most likely) have to switch the CPU from `AArch64` to `AArch32` execution. eg. this slide-show covers the topic: [Linux on AArch64 ARM 64-bit Architecture](https://events.static.linuxfound.org/images/stories/pdf/lcna_co2012_marinas.pdf).

Q: Is there a way to use a 32bit library on a 64bit Android device?

---

As it turned out, this is not accepted by Google Play - providing ARM64 native assembly is required.

Comment: "despite they claim Android 8.0 (which is ARM64 only)": what makes you think Android 8.x is 64 bit only ?

Comment: @Marged because there are no 32bit QEMU images (API level 25 is the last one); nor an Oreo update for the Nexus 6, which is a Snapdragon 805 (but only the Nexus 6 P, which is a Snapdragon 810)... any example of an `armv7l` device, which runs Oreo (except custom ROM, alike SIX)?

Comment: OK, but Android 8.x runs on (physical) 32 bit devices too

Comment: the SIX ROM indeed proofs, that it is possible, but Google stopped supporting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any arm64 CPU you find in a smartphone should also be able to run arm32 code.

There are, however, at least three requirements that need to be fulfilled:

1. Your process cannot mix 64-bit and 32-bit code -- it needs to be one or the other.
2. Your operating system (or you) must provide 32-bit versions of all the dynamic libraries you link to.
3. Your OS kernel must have support for 32-bit processes; it will be responsible for switching the execution mode while your process is using the CPU.

Number 3 is fine; Android uses a [Linux-like](http://kroah.com/log/blog/2018/08/24/what-stable-kernel-should-i-use/) kernel, which supports arm32 processes on arm64.

Number 2 is *probably* fine; I don't know where you heard that Android 8.0 is 64-bit only, but it's not true. It is possible for a device manufacturer to choose to exclude 32-bit support, but I don't know any that do (because it would prevent 32-bit-only legacy apps and games from running on their devices).

Of course, shipping both 32-bit and 64-bit libraries on phones means that the OS takes up more storage space, so it's definitely possible that 64-bit-only devices will be a thing in the future. No 32-bit-only games or apps will work on those devices.

Number 1 is your problem: your app is running as a 64-bit process, and is trying to load a 32-bit library. This will not work.

The solution would be to make your app 32-bit-only. If you can avoid it all, though, I would recommend against it (i.e. don't use that library). Your app would not work on any 64-bit-only devices that might be released in the future.

**2023 update**

It is now the future!

Google's Pixel 7 series [come without OS support for 32-bit applications](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2022/10/64-bit-only-devices.html).

Also, starting this or next year, [new ARM CPUs will not have 32-bit support at all](https://www.arm.com/blogs/blueprint/64-bit).

> we are announcing that all Arm Cortex-A CPU mobile cores will be 64-bit only from 2023.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, which provided some hint to me. when I put the library into `armeabi` instead, it complains `Unable to strip library '...lib/armeabi/somelibrary.so' due to missing strip tool for ABI 'ARMEABI'. Packaging it as is.` ...but, one can actually use it.

Comment: I think that warning indicates that you're missing some 32-bit NDK tools, but I'm not sure.

Comment: it only happens with the `armeabi` directory (which seems to work for both architectures), not the `armeabi-v7a` directory (which is explicitly 32bit).